# SUM from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables:

- `order`
- `orderline` (has `orderID`)
- `orderactions` (has `orderID`)

Then I need `SUM(of orderline.price)` and `SUM(of orderactions.price)` per `orderID`.

When I used:

```
    SELECT order.ID, SUM(orderlines.price), SUM(orderactions.price) 
    FROM order 
    LEFT JOIN orderlines ON orderlines.orderID=order.ID
    LEFT JOIN orderactions ON orderactions.orderID=order.ID
    WHERE order.ID=@orderID
    GROUP BY order.ID
```

I got a result from `orderactions` which a equivalent to `SUM(orderactions.price)*quantity` of orderlines for this order.ID

Only solution I found, which given me a right result, are sub-query for every "SUM"-table:

```
SELECT order.ID
, (SELECT SUM(orderlines.price) FROM orderlines WHERE orderlines.orderId=order.ID)
, (SELECT SUM(orderactions.price) FROM orderactions WHERE orderactions.orderId=order.ID)
FROM order
WHERE order.ID=@orderID
```

Question: is there some other (faster) solution for this, because sub-queries are slow and we try to not using them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your select only runs the two *very simple* subqueries once each, I'd say you're pretty close to optimal for your query. There is no need to add a `JOIN` unless the queries are correlated in some way.

The slow part about subqueries is usually that the database may (if you're not careful how you write your query) non obviously execute them more than once. This normally happens if they depend on external values that may change per row, ie when you `JOIN` them in some way.

Your subqueries are straight forward enough and not using any external values other than your constant, so in your case, they only execute once each, and there is nothing in them that is simplified by adding a `JOIN`.

Comment: thanks @Joachim Isaksson. I put WHERE clause only for simple example. So for example if I will need to count a difference for orderedPrices and Actionsprices per order for all orders i order table, so then sub-querys will execute thousands-millions times

Answer (score 1):

depends of your data this way can be a solution:

```
    SELECT order.ID, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN orderlines.orderID IS NOT NULL THEN orderlines.price ELSE 0 END), 
    SUM(CASE WHEN orderactions.orderID IS NOT NULL THEN orderactions.price ELSE 0 END) 
FROM order 
LEFT JOIN orderlines ON orderlines.orderID=order.ID
LEFT JOIN orderactions ON orderactions.orderID=order.ID
WHERE order.ID=@orderID
GROUP BY order.ID
```

Comment: The problem is, the join breaks the result, this test case will show the difference to the working query in the question; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/35d4b/1

Comment: Thanks @httpskk but your solution is same as my first(wrong) solution only added NULL handling. I diddn't put here but using always ISNULL(price,0)